# How do I wait for a set of threads to 'really' finish in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a group of threads in java that i want to run several times (each time with a different set of parameters). for the second run to start i want to wait for the first run to finish. this should be easily accomplished with `Thread.join()` before the second run, but since my threads run in an infinite loop i have to stop them with an interrupt, which also interrupts the blocking join:

I have a thread whose `run()` method looks basically like this:

```
try {  
    while(true) {  
        printSomeInfo();
        if (...) {
            Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().interrupt();
        }
    } 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {  
    Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().interrupt();  
} finally {  
    printStats();
}
```

and a main method invoking the run method of the thread:

```
System.out.println("New run:");
for (i ...) {    //first run
    myThread[i] = new MyThread(someInfoString1);
    myThread[i].start();
}
try {
    for (i...) {
        myThread[i].join();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("New run:");
for (i ...) {    //second run
    myThread[i] = new MyThread(someInfoString2);
    myThread[i].start();
}
try {
    for (i...) {
        myThread[i].join();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My problem is that the second run starts printing out the info, without the first run being finished printing out with the printStats() method in the finally block.
So the output looks like this:

```
New run:
Info 1
Info 1
...
Info 1
New run:
(here comes the stack trace)
Info 2
Info 2
Stats 1    <- this should happen before the second "New run:"
...
Info 2
Stats 2
```

how can i really wait for the first set of threads to finish? is there maybe a more selective way to interrupt the running threads?

Comment: [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

Comment: If a bit of code must run after another bit, why not use one thread?

Comment: Because some parts should be done in parallel? The OP is using *one* thread to orchestrate the other threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your repeated use of `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().interrupt()` which interrupts *all* threads in your `ThreadGroup`, including the one which called `join`.

If you look at your loop, you are catching the `InterruptedException`, but not recovering correctly. Your loop is contained within the `try…catch` block and hence forcibly terminated by the exception. Since you want to call `join` on all threads, you must proceed with the loop, including the one `join` call that has been interrupted:

```
threads: for (i...) { // loop over all threads
    for(;;) { // recover join on InterruptedException
        try {
            myThread[i].join();
            continue threads; // after successful join
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {} // call join again
    }
}
```

Generally, interrupting an entire `ThreadGroup`, or dealing with the outdated concept of thread groups at all, is not a proper software design. You should rewrite your software to interrupt the inteded threads only. Or simply use the concurrency framework, esp.  `ExecutorService` which already provides ways to submit groups of tasks and cancel or wait for all.